# Pitch Detection using AutoCorrelation

Tags: c, pitch

I am using auto correlation function to detect pitch of the signal. I am using the equation
acf(s)=(1/n)*sigma(|x(n)-x(n+s)|)

How do i proceed from here.
Should i find the minimum and the pitch is the index of the minimum. In this case the pitch is always 0. Am I doing it correctly?
I need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first minimum in the autocorrelation function identifies the fundamental period (so logn as the original data is not too noisy). This will be a number of samples, `N`, so you need to convert this to frequency, e.g.

```
pitch = Fs / N
```

where `Fs` is the sampling frequency.